# Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number

Tags: workflow, formula, process-builder

My requirement is to update a field for emails read every time the Pardot Score increases by one.  I have a flow that does this but I would like to get into a more bulletproof workflow rule.

My the field to hold the value is a number field. If the Pardot Score is changed by one I want the Pardot Emails open field to increase by 1. I  can't see why I am getting an error here.  The field Pardot_Emails_Opened__c is a number field. The field pi_score__c is part of a managed package from Pardot.

My criteria: `ISCHANGED(pi__score__c) && 
PRIORVALUE(pi__score__c) - pi__score__c= 1`

My action: `Pardot_Emails_Opened__c = PRIORVALUE(Pardot_Emails_Opened__c) + 1`

Comment: Are you getting the error while creating the formula or when the workflow rule is executing? If it is coming while exection. Can you try  by updating action as: `Pardot_Emails_Opened__c = VALUE(PRIORVALUE(Pardot_Emails_Opened__c) + 1)`

Comment: The error happens while creating the rule.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the field types by editing your question?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did. Post has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually break down your formula logic for the new value, you are attempting to set a boolean value since your formula is actually an expression and not an assignment. Lets take a peek:

> Pardot_Emails_Opened__c = PRIORVALUE(Pardot_Emails_Opened__c) + 1

What you are actually saying here is `"Does the value of emails opened equal the old value of emails opened plus one?"` This is a boolean expression, and will return a true or false based on the number of emails opened.

What I think you are trying to do is actually add 1 to the number of emails opened, which would not include an assignment operator. Instead, have the workflow update your field, and in the formula condition for the new value, simply set its new value:

> PRIORVALUE(Pardot_Emails_Opened__c) + 1