# Workflow rule to update contact field. Syntax error missing ")"

Tags: workflow, error, compile-error

I have a custom object with a picklist field. When the picklist is selected I want a field on the contact object to be filled with the selected value. I am trying to create the formula for the rule but  it says I am missing a ")"

```
ISPICKVAL( Type_of_pet__c, 'Dog' 'Cat' 'Bird'))
```

Please help me!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_ispickval.htm&type=5

Comment: I updated the code to OR(ISPICKVAL( Type_of_pet__c, 'Dog' ),ISPICKVAL( Type_of_pet__c, 'Cat' ),ISPICKVAL( Type_of_pet__c, 'Bird')) but now the error says Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230250/error-formula-result-is-data-type-boolean-incompatible-with-expected-data-ty)

Answer (score 1):

So the calc would be something like this (using a case statement):

```
CASE(1, 
   IF(ISPICKVAL​ (Type_of_pet__c, "Dog"),​ 1, 0), "Dog",​​
   IF(ISPICKVAL​ (Type_of_pet__c, "Cat"),​ 1, 0), "Cat",​​
   IF(ISPICKVAL​ (Type_of_pet__c, "Bird"),​ 1, 0), "Bird"
   )
```

Depending on the field type you could just skip all this and reflect the value itself - just `TEXT(Type_of_pet__c)`

Comment: This worked! Thank you Caspar!!

Comment: If this worked, you should generally mark this answer as accepted, cheers.